# Time complexity analysis of Kruskal's Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, trees, discrete-optimization, analysis-of-algorithms

Hello I have a doubt about the time complexity of Kruskal's Algorithm.

Symbols:

$E \implies$ Total number of edges in the graph

$V \implies$ Total number of vertices in the graph

$O \implies$ Big $O$ notation for calculating the upper bound of the function(as tight as possible)

Tools used:

Binary Heap => Create: $O(n)$. Pop: $\log(n)$. Peek: $O(1)$

Union Find(DSU) => Using chain compression and rank compression. Amortised time complexity comes out to be Ackerman function which I assumed to be $O(1)$ because I am working with a dense enough graph

Algorithm:

1. Create a binary heap and dump all the edges with weight as the sorting factor into this heap. Time complexity $= O(E)$
2. Create a loop($V-1$ times as those are the number of edges we need) that goes over and do:

2.1. Peek for the minimum weight edge $O(\log(E))$ and find parent of set in union set which takes $O(1)$ time.

2.2 Union of different sets $O(1)$ time again.

2.3 Take this edge $O(1)$ time again.

2.4 Goto 2.1 if $V-1$ iterations are not over

So according to this, the time complexity feels to be $O((V-1)(\log(E)))$ which is $O(V\log E)$.

The given time complexity $O(E\log V)$ or $O(E\log E)$ is also correct as Big $O$ notation is just the upper bound but I want a tight upper bound.

Can you explain on my analysis.

[Here](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-cost-to-connect-all-points/submissions/1050316239/) is a dense graph using Kruskal's Algorithm as mentioned above for reference in C++ (using Leetcode programming problem as an example)

Comment: Hi! What's your doubt? If the time complexity is $O(E\log V)$ or $O(E\log E)$? Btw I highly recommend you to read [how to ask good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) because the formatting is a little bit strange :)

Comment: My time complexity is O(VlogE) which is incorrect I presume. Through this question I want to know the reason why is it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in getting an $O(\log E)$ running time for a single iteration of the algorithm, but you are wrong about needing only $V-1$ iterations.

Remember, Kruskal's algorithm does not add every single edge it encounters to the future spanning tree. An edge is *only* added if it connects two different components of the forest built so far.

This means that we cannot be sure that we're done after $V-1$ steps; that's just the best case, if we're lucky and the first $V-1$ edges were all usable. In the worst case, all $E$ steps will be necessary: maybe the most expensive edge, the one we'd rather not use until we exhaust all other possibilities, is the *only* edge connecting two sets of vertices.

This is why the running time is $O(E \log E)$.

(Also, if your analysis *were* correct, then you still don't get $O(V \log E)$. Don't forget about step 1, which is $O(E)$. The only safe way to combine the two parts of your analysis would be $O(E + V \log E)$; depending on how many edges there are in the graph, either term could be higher than the other. On the other hand, once we put an $O(E \log E)$ bound on the loop's running time, we can ignore the $O(E)$ term.)